# orthAgogue incorrectly processing BLAST files

Tags: terminal, bioinformatics

Need to recruit the help of any budding bioinformaticians that are lurking in the shadows here.

I am currently in the process of formatting some `.fasta` files for use in a set of grouping programs but I cannot for the life of me get them to work. First things first, all the files have to have a 3 or 4 character name such as the following:

```
PP41.fasta
PP59.fasta
PPBD.fasta
...etc...
```

The files must have headers for each gene sequence that look like so: `>xxxx|yyyyyyyyyy` where xxxx is the same 3 or 4 letter 'taxon' identifier as the file names I put above and yyyyyyy is a numerical identifier for each of the proteins within each of the taxons (the pipe symbol can also be replaced with an _ as below). I then `cat` all of these in to one file which has a header that looks correct like so:

```
>PP49_00001
MIENFNENNDMSDMFWEVEKGTGEVINLVPNTSNTVQPVVLMRLGLFVPTLKSTKRGHQG
EMSSMDATAELRQLAIVKTEGYENIHITGARLDMDNDFKTWVGIIHSFAKHKVIGDAVTL
SFVDFIKLCGIPSSRSSKRLRERLGASLRRIATNTLSFSSQNKSYHTHLVQSAYYDMVKD
TVTIQADPKIFELYQFDRKVLLQLRAINELGRKESAQALYTYIESLPPSPAPISLARLRA
RLNLRSRVTTQNAIVRKAMEQLKGIGYLDYTEIKRGSSVYFIVHARRPKLKALKSSKSSF
KRKKETQEESILTELTREELELLEIIRAEKIIKVTRNHRRKKQTLLTFAEDESQ*
>PP49_00002
MQNDIILPINKLHGLKLLNSLELSDIELGELLSLEGDIKQVSTGNNGIVVHRIDMSEIGS
FLIIDSGESRFVIKAS*
```

Next step is to construct a blast database which I do as follows, using the `formatdb` tool of NCBI Blast:

```
formatdb -i allproteins.fasta -p T -o T
```

This produces a set of files for the database. Next I conduct an all-vs-all BLAST of the concatenated proteins against the database that I made of them like so, which outputs a tabular file which I suspect is where my issues are beginning to arise:

```
blastall -p blastp -d allproteins.fasta -i allproteins.fasta -a 6 -F '0 S' -v 100000 -b 100000 -e 1e-5 -m 8 -o plasmid_allvall_blastout
```

These files have 12 columns and look like the below. It *appears* correct to me, but my supervisor suspects the error is in the blast file - I don't know what I'm doing wrong however.

```
PP49_00001  PP51_00025  100.00  354 0   0   1   354 1   354 0.0  552
PP49_00001  PP49_00001  100.00  354 0   0   1   354 1   354 0.0  552
PP49_00001  PPTI_00026  90.28   288 28  0   1   288 1   288 3e-172   476
PP49_00001  PPNP_00026  90.28   288 28  0   1   288 1   288 3e-172   476
PP49_00001  PPKC_00016  89.93   288 29  0   1   288 1   288 2e-170   472
PP49_00001  PPBD_00021  89.93   288 29  0   1   288 1   288 2e-170   472
PP49_00001  PPJN_00003  91.14   79  7   0   145 223 2   80  8e-47    147
PP49_00002  PPTI_00024  100.00  76  0   0   1   76  1   76  3e-50    146
PP49_00002  PPNP_00024  100.00  76  0   0   1   76  1   76  3e-50    146
PP49_00002  PPKC_00018  100.00  76  0   0   1   76  1   76  3e-50    146
```

**SO**, this is where the problems really begin. I now pass the above file to a program called orthAgogue which analyses the paired sequences I have above using parameters laid out in the manual (still no idea if I'm doing anything wrong) - all I know is the several output files that are produced are all just nonsense/empty.

Command looks like so:

```
orthAgogue -i plasmid_allvsall_blastout -t 0 -p 1 -e 5 -O .
```

Any and all ideas welcome! (Hope I've covered everything - sorry about the long post!)

***EDIT*** Never did manage to find a solution to this. Had to use an alternative piece of software. If admins wish to close this please do, unless it is worth having open for someone else (though I suspect its a pretty niche issue).

Comment: Your main problem is that your supervisor says that it is wrong the output of blastall and you don't know why? For example the second line is comparing the same sequence, therefore it will have a p-value of 0, they are identical! Did you check the manuals about the meaning of the parameters you use?

Comment: It's more a case of he thinks its wrong, but neither of us knows why! :/ 

As for the self-matches, to the best of my knowledge, that is meant to happen since you match the entire dataset back against itself in an all-vs-all comparison, so I don't think it's those entries that are causing my problems.

Comment: But there must be a reason why he thinks it is wrong. Did you follow the guidelines/tutorials, standard procedure? Do you really understand what means each option you use and are you able to explain your supervisor why you should use them?

Comment: I'm happy with all the arguments bar the -b and -v as the guidlines I'm following call them "don't care" values - so I'm black boxing it a little bit. I'm happy with the tabular output of blast, I understand what each field represents etc. The main reason he suspects the blast file is because it's orthAgogue that fails and the blast file is what you supply to it - though the exact nature of why its wrong we don't know at this point. Something I'm doing leading up to it is almost certainly to blame (I am a novice) - but I just can't see it.

Comment: Did you check what are the specifications of orthAgogue about the input, did you post your problems in their mailing list or support? Maybe it is just the format of the input or that you found a bug in the program or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discovered this issue (of orthAgogue) first today:

- though my reply may be old, I hope it may help future users;
- issue is due to a missing parameter: seems like you forgot to specify the separator: *-s '_'*, ie, the following set of command-line parameters should do the trick*:

  orthAgogue -i plasmid_allvsall_blastout -t 0 -p 1 -e 5 -O -s '_'

(* Under the assumption that your input-file is a tabular-seperated file of columns.)

*A brief update after comment made by Joe:*

In brief, the problem described in the intiail error report (by Joe) is (in most cases) not a bug. Instead it is one of the core properties of the Inparanoid algorithm which orthAgogue implements: if your ortholog-result-file is empty (though constructed), this (in most cases) implies that there are no reciprocal best match between a protein-pair from two different taxa/species.

One (of many) explanations for this could be that your blastp-scores are too similar, a case where I would suggest a combined tree-based/homology clustering as in TREEFAM.

Therefore, when I receive your data, I'll send it to one of the biologists I'm working with, with goal of identifying the tool proper for your data: hope my last comment makes your day ;)

*Ole Kristian Ekseth, developer of orthAgogue*

Comment: Thanks Ole, I appreciate your replying even at this late stage. It was obviously a while a go now, but I'm fairly sure I tried giving orthAgogue no specified separator, and the `-s '_'` and `-s '|'` options. Neither seem to work. It appears to be something inherent in the blast file. If you're interested, I can supply you the potentially troublesome files if you'd like to explore the issue for development purposes?

Comment: Hi, would be great: what I did when rectifying this issue (ie, marking it as resolved) was to parse your example into a new text-file. From what you say, a potential explanation could be some of the 'blank symbols' in your file causing an improper result, ie, it would be great having a look upon your input! ;)

Comment: OK fantastic, I would be interested to see if its something really basic I have missed. The files are currently on the server at work, do you have a preferred way of me sending the file(s) to you? Email/Dropbox or something?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In brief, I like your suggestion, ie, if the file(s) are of pretty small size (ie, less than 20 MB) then send them to my gmail-account oekseth@gmail.com . Alternatively I suggest you place the file(s) in a Dropbox-folder, and then providing me with a user-access to the latter. Hope this sounds like a plan: what do you think?

Comment: Yep sounds good. I'll work on sending you them tomorrow. I'll email you with the files, or a link to the dropbox/google drive if they are too large! Appreciate the help :)